# Success message in module front controller

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm actually using the [Tools class](https://github.com/iwanwan/Prestashop-1.5/blob/master/classes/Tools.php) in Prestashop 1.5 that allows me to display error messages to the front-end:

```
$this->errors[] = Tools::displayError( 'Fatal error!' );
```

Is there any function to display **success** messages the same way?
It seems that we can't use the `l()` function inside of an extended `ModuleFrontController()`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution but it's probably not the best:

Inside of my `ModuleFrontController()` class:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'success', 'Success!' );
```

At the top of my module's template file:

```
{if isset($success)}
    <p class="success">{$success}</p>
{/if}
```

It displays "Success!" as intented.

Comment: I didn't notice until now but downvoting this when the answer is typically the same as the one that has been upvoted is stupid.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are displaying errors / success messages like below :

```
{if isset($success)}
    <p class="success">{$success}</p>
{/if}
```

is good option. Please note that

```
Tools::displayError('Fatal error');
```

is not providing you any sort of styling for error messages, it just provides a way for translating errors at admin.

If you want your success messages should be translatable also then in your controller do it as followed :

```
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'success', 1 );
```

And then in your template file

```
{if isset($success)}

   {l s='This is success message'}  

{/if}
```

And if template file is in a module then use it as

```
{if isset($success)}

    {l s='This is success message' mod='yourmodulename'}  

{/if}
```

Hope this will help you.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For **success messages** you can use:

```
$output = null;
$output .= $this->displayConfirmation('<message goes here!>');
```

For **error messages** you can use:

```
$output = null;  
$output .= $this->displayError('<message goes here!>');
```

an in the end:

```
return $output;
```

or something like:

```
return $output.$this->displayForm();
```

Comment: The problem was not to display a message or an error but how to properly assign it to a template file.

Answer (score 0):

It is works for me in PrestaShop 1.7

```
$this->errors[] = "Error message!";
$this->success[] = "Success message!";
```